# Accessing DOM in Angular 2 RC

Tags: angular

What is the proper way to manipulate the DOM in Angular 2 RC?

For instance, I'm building a service for debug purposes to swap out .css file references in the document .

Prior to Angular 2 RC, it was possible to use `BrowserDomAdapter` from DOM manipulations, like so:

```
import { BrowserDomAdapter } from 'angular2/platform/browser';

...
constructor(private domAdapter: BrowserDomAdapter) {
}
...

const document = this.domAdapter.defaultDoc();
```

This was inspired by the `Title` service (now in `@angular/platform-browser`). It seems that the `Title` service still uses it internally, but it is no longer exported for use outside of Angular. I.e.

```
import { BrowserDomAdapter } from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

Results in:

```
Module '".../@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported member 'BrowserDomAdapter'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not exported and there is no alternative. I'd create a bug report to get it exported again. It was mentioned a few times in comments that it should not be used by external developers anyway but I never saw an explanation what else should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks, @GünterZöchbauer. I'll try GitHub. And thanks for the answer, you're an Angular2 beast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```ts
  import {BrowserDomAdapter} from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter';
```

---

**UPDATE:(comment)**

> an [issue on GitHub](http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509#issuecomment-217483301) explains that the removal was indeed
>   accidental, so hopefully it will be back in rc2.  - @paul

Comment: That can only be a workaround. We are not supposed to import from `src/...` because that is considered private implementation.

Comment: Exactly. just a workaround. Maybe they forgot to export it or for some reason just didn't.

Comment: an issue on GitHub explains that the removal was indeed accidental, so hopefully it will be back in rc2. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509#issuecomment-217483301

Comment: Won't be back, but the discussion in the GitHub issue suggests what to use instead.

Answer (score 3):

For people like me, looking forward for interacting with the DOM in `angular 2.4`:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({})
export class MyClass {

    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    doSomething() {
        this.document.someMethodOfDocument();
    }
}
```

You should not use any adapter. This is implementation detail and should not be used. Instead `@Inject(DOCUMENT)` into your component and use it.

Further reading: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509

Comment: This looks like a copy/paste of Falx's comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509#issuecomment-224703913